# Receiving error with Custom Tables plugin

Tags: plugins, errors

How to resolve this warning which is shown when I use the Custom Tables plugin? Can anybody help me please

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ..\wp-content\plugins\custom-tables\pages\show_table.php on line 378

Comment: -1: Your question is leaning on too localized; you refused an edit that made it less so; you have not accepted any answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty "fix" would be to change line 378 in that file and cast the `$qry` variable to an array. It should make the error go away, however, to fix the actual cause of the problem some refactoring may need to be done. You could drop the plugin author a note.

```
foreach ($qry as $row) {
// becomes:
foreach ((array) $qry as $row) {
```

Comment: thanx man its working :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Login to your WordPress admin and visit the *Plugins > Editor* page
2. Select **Custom tables** from the drop-down list
3. Select the `show_tables.php` file from the right-hand panel.
4. Scroll down until you see this line: `$qry = $wpdb->get_results($abfrage);`
5. Change that line to: `$qry = $wpdb->get_results($abfrage, ARRAY_A);`

I can't guarantee that doing this will work; I haven't tested it myself just yet. I'll edit this answer when I have. Post a comment below if you cannot complete one of steps above, for whatever reason.

Comment: i tried it but not working :(